# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `myuserid' for #<Userdetail:0x007f3e631929d8>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am trying to create a rails app,My app working fine locally but when I deployed it on Heroku its giving error.I have tried all other solutions on stackoverflow but not any working for me.

```html
 Rendered userdetails/new.html.erb within layouts/application (69.0ms)
2014-11-09T17:38:23.427665+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/userdetails/new" for 113.193.105.11 at 2014-11-09 17:38:23 +0000
2014-11-09T17:38:23.511449+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 80ms
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513446+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/userdetails/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_userdetails_new_html_erb__4090279191377710950_69952963663860'
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513443+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/userdetails/_form.html.erb:24:in `block in _app_views_userdetails__form_html_erb___1876473002485377605_69952963666180'
2014-11-09T17:38:23.511258+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered userdetails/_form.html.erb (67.7ms)
2014-11-09T17:38:23.430938+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UserdetailsController#new as HTML
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513448+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513426+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513429+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `myuserid' for #<Userdetail:0x007f3e631929d8>):
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513430+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:   </div>
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513433+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <div class="field">
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513435+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:       <%= f.label :myuserid , 'User ID'%><br>
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513436+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:       <%= f.text_field :myuserid %>
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513438+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:   </div>
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513439+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:   <div class="field">
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513441+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:     <%= f.label :birthday %><br>
2014-11-09T17:38:23.513445+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/userdetails/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_userdetails__form_html_erb___1876473002485377605_69952963666180'
```

My userdetail/new.html.erb looks like

```html
<h1>New userdetail</h1>


<%= render 'form',userdetail: @userdetail  %>


<%= link_to 'Back', userdetails_path %>
```

and My userdetail/_form.html looks like

```html
<%= form_for(@userdetail) do |f| %>
  <% if @userdetail.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@userdetail.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this userdetail from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @userdetail.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :myuserid , 'User ID'%><br>
      <%= f.text_field :myuserid %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :birthday %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :birthday %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :gender %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :gender %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :contact_number %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :contact_number %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :country %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :state %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :city %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :gre_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :gre_date %>
  </div>
  
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %> 

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My userdetail controller looks like

```html
class UserdetailsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_userdetail, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  #User can only edit or destroy its own details
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /userdetails
  # GET /userdetails.json
  def index
    @userdetails = Userdetail.all
  end

  # GET /userdetails/1
  # GET /userdetails/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /userdetails/new
  def new
   @userdetail = Userdetail.new
   
  end

  # GET /userdetails/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /userdetails
  # POST /userdetails.json
  def create
    @userdetail = Userdetail.new(userdetail_params)

   
   @userdetail.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @userdetail.save
        format.html { redirect_to @userdetail, notice: 'Userdetail was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @userdetail }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @userdetail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /userdetails/1
  # PATCH/PUT /userdetails/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @userdetail.update(userdetail_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @userdetail, notice: 'Userdetail was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @userdetail }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @userdetail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /userdetails/1
  # DELETE /userdetails/1.json
  def destroy
    @userdetail.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to userdetails_url, notice: 'Userdetail was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_userdetail
      @userdetail = Userdetail.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def userdetail_params
      params.require(:userdetail).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :myuserid, :birthday, :gender, :contact_number, :address, :country, :state, :city, :gre_date)
    end

    def correct_user

      @user = @userdetail.user_id

      redirect_to( userdetails_url) unless @user == current_user.id
    end
end
```

My user detail model looks like

```html
class Userdetail < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  #validates that one user can create just one user details
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :message => "details already exist"

end
```

My db schema looks like

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141108175213) do

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "issue",       default: "", null: false
    t.text     "description", default: "", null: false
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "topic_id"
  end

  create_table "topics", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "issue",      default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "userdetails", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.date     "birthday"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "contact_number"
    t.text     "address"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "city"
    t.date     "gre_date"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "myuserid"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "userdetails", ["myuserid"], name: "index_userdetails_on_myuserid", unique: true
  add_index "userdetails", ["user_id"], name: "index_userdetails_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Please tell me answer. I generated app's view and model using command rails g scaffold userdetail but added 'myuserid' column later.Please see any if there is any other fault inn my code and suggest correction 
Also my directory contain automatically generated duplicate files with ~ at the end of name, Any idea ?

Comment: Instead of `myuserid` type: `user_id` in both label and text_field

Comment: I have separate user_id column, myuserid is different field of type string

Comment: I am updating schema checkout

Comment: @BroiSatse I have added schema of my database

Comment: Did you do `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: yes I did and I also did heroku restart

Comment: Best way to debug is `heroku run rails console` then in the console try `Userdetail.new`. Does that output `=> #<Userdetail myuserid: nil`?

Comment: Its not showing myuserid columne

Comment: Means heroku didn't created myuserid column, How I can create that in Heroku

Comment: Did you remember to include migration in the commit?

Comment: Yes I did git add --all and git add . , and I have also checked schema in heroku console. myuserid column is there in heroku

Comment: Thanks @Mbesto I found answer because of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, when i ran rails console in heroku I found that myuserid column was not created in heroku. When i check my migration files I found that the migration file creating myuserid column was accidentally deleted. I recreated that file and my app start working.